# jquery quicksand plugin css issue

Tags: jquery, css, quicksand

I'm trying to include the excellent quicksand plugin onto a site. I would say it's about 90% complete. The only issue i'm having is that when I try to filter my result set they all float over to the left hand side of the page before sorting themselves out. Here is an example

http://newroad.tizuni.com/therapists/find-a-therapist/

Can anybody shed some light on what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please add some code to your question.

Comment: Can't help but think this falls into **too localised**.. can you produce the same issue with a small snippet of code..? Your site uses numerous plugins which could be conflicting with quicksand, we'd rather not debug your code for you...